# How to install FreeCodeCamp on my own server?

Tags: github

As an open source project, can I install FreeCodeCamp on my own server? Which language they are using, and what steps do I need to take? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can install on your own server.
As you can see from [FreeCodeCamp repository](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp), it's using javascript.
[getting-started](https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp/blob/staging/CONTRIBUTING.md#getting-started) is a tutorial for you to install it.